# How to update a specific position value in a comma/pipeline separated text column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

below is the sample data

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 23,24,32,xyz,78 |
| 21 | xx,32,ss,11,78 |
| 22 | pqr,sql,2,77a,67 |

Now how can I update the 4th position value of column2 as 'TRUE'.
For record 1 the value 'xyz' would be replaced by 'TRUE',
for record 2 the value '11' would be replaced by 'TRUE',
for record 3 the value '77a' would be replaced by 'TRUE'

The update table would look like:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 23,24,32,TRUE,78 |
| 21 | xx,32,ss,TRUE,78 |
| 22 | pqr,sql,2,TRUE,67 |

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the comma separated string into an array, unnest that array and while aggregating back  into the dreaded comma separated string, replace the value at the fourth position:

```
update badly_designed_table
   set column2 = (select string_agg(case idx when 4 then 'TRUE' else ch end, ',')
                  from unnest(string_to_array(column2, ',')) with ordinality as x(ch, idx))
;
```

If you need that frequently, you can write a function that sets the value at a specific position of such a string.

The correct solution however is to **not** store data this way.

If you really need to de-normalize your model, then at least use a proper array rather than a comma separated string.